# Find last sequence episode and increment count variable

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, sequence, increment

My data looks like this (person-period file), where `hldid` represents a unique identifier, `variable` represents *time* and `paid` is a dummy vector of interest

```
   hldid variable paid
1      1        1    0
2      1        2    0
3      1        3    0
4      1        4    1
5      1        5    1
6      1        6    0
7      1        7    1
8      1        8    1
9      1        9    0
10     1       10    0
11     2        1    0
12     2        2    0
13     2        3    1
14     2        4    1
15     2        5    0
16     2        6    1
17     2        7    0
18     2        8    0
19     2        9    0
20     2       10    0
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
  hldid variable  paid  last wwork2
 1     1        1     0     0      0
 2     1        2     0     0      0
 3     1        3     0     0      0
 4     1        4     1     0      0
 5     1        5     1     0      0
 6     1        6     0     0     -2
 7     1        7     1     0     -1
 8     1        8     1     1      0
 9     1        9     0     0      1
10     1       10     0     0      2
11     2        1     0     0      0
12     2        2     0     0      0
13     2        3     1     0      0
14     2        4     1     0     -2
15     2        5     0     0     -1
16     2        6     1     1      0
17     2        7     0     0      1
18     2        8     0     0      2
19     2        9     0     0      0
20     2       10     0     0      0
```

I would like to create a vector that (1) finds the latest episode of `paid` for each `hldid` and (2) to decrement/increment 2 episodes before and 2 episodes after the last episode of `paid`.

So far, this is what I did.

1. Find last episode of `paid`

What is complicated here is that paid is not a continuous sequence. For instance `hldid == 1` stops paid at episode 6 and starts again at episode 7 and the last episode is at 8.

So my idea is to subset all the `paid == 1`, count the number of episodes and then merge it back. However, I am not sure this is the most efficient strategy.

```
ddw = dta %>% filter(paid == 1)
ddw$work = 0

for(i in 2:nrow(ddw)){
  if(ddw$hldid[i] == ddw$hldid[i-1] & 
     ddw$paid[i] == 1){
    ddw$work[i] <- ddw$work[i-1] + 1 
 }
}

ddf = merge(dta, ddw, by = c('hldid', 'variable', 'paid'), all = T)
```

Then, I find the last episode with

```
ddw2 = ddf %>% group_by(hldid) %>% mutate(end_work = ifelse(work == max(work, na.rm = T), variable, 0))
```

and finally I create a dummy indicating the position of the final `paid` episode

```
ddw2$end_work[is.na(ddw2$end_work)] <- 0
ddw2 = ddw2 %>% group_by(hldid) %>% mutate(wwork = ifelse(end_work == variable, 1, 0))
```

2. Increment/decrement

Now, from here I don't know how to increment/decrement before and after the last episode. So far I could only come up with this:

```
df = ddw2
df$wwork2 = 0

for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  if(df$hldid[i] == df$hldid[i-1] & 
     df$wwork[i] == 1){
    df$wwork2[i-1] <- 1; df$wwork2[i] <- 1; df$wwork2[i+1] <- 1
  }
}
```

### data

```
dta = rbind(c(1,1,0), 
      c(1,2,0), 
      c(1,3,0), 
      c(1,4,1), 
      c(1,5,1), 
      c(1,6,0), 
      c(1,7,1), 
      c(1,8,1), 
      c(1,9,0), 
      c(1,10,0), 
      c(2,1,0), 
      c(2,2,0), 
      c(2,3,1), 
      c(2,4,1), 
      c(2,5,0), 
      c(2,6,1), 
      c(2,7,0), 
      c(2,8,0), 
      c(2,9,0), 
      c(2,10,0)) 

colnames(dta) = c('hldid', 'variable', 'paid')
dta = as.data.frame(dta)

library(dplyr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, group by `hldid`, then define `end_work` as the difference between `variable` and the max value for which `paid==1`, then insert 0s for values greater than 2...

```
library(dplyr)
dta2 <- dta %>% group_by(hldid) %>% 
                mutate(last=as.numeric(variable==max(variable[paid==1]))) %>%
                mutate(end_work=variable-max(variable[paid==1])) %>%
                mutate(end_work=replace(end_work,abs(end_work)>2,0))

dta2
   hldid variable  paid  last end_work
   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1        1     0     0        0
 2     1        2     0     0        0
 3     1        3     0     0        0
 4     1        4     1     0        0
 5     1        5     1     0        0
 6     1        6     0     0       -2
 7     1        7     1     0       -1
 8     1        8     1     1        0
 9     1        9     0     0        1
10     1       10     0     0        2
11     2        1     0     0        0
12     2        2     0     0        0
13     2        3     1     0        0
14     2        4     1     0       -2
15     2        5     0     0       -1
16     2        6     1     1        0
17     2        7     0     0        1
18     2        8     0     0        2
19     2        9     0     0        0
20     2       10     0     0        0
```

The end of work episode by id can be summarised by

```
end_w <- dta %>% group_by(hldid) %>% summarise(end_episode=max(variable[paid==1]))

end_w
  hldid end_episode
  <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1           8
2     2           6
```

Comment: that's a seriously neat code thanks! what is this `replace` function doing exactly? thanks

Comment: `replace` is just replacing the values of the first argument, for which the second argument is true, with the third argument, keeping the the others unchanged.  So it is keeping `end_work` between -2 and +2 and setting the rest to 0.

Comment: very cool ... one thing I realise I forgot, I also need a vector indicating the end of work episode. I m just updating it if you dont mind.

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dta)[,  c('last', 'wwork2') := {
       i1 <- which.max(cumsum(paid))
       i2 <- seq_len(.N) - i1
     .(as.integer(seq_len(.N) ==i1), i2*(abs(i2) <=2))
         },  by = hldid]

df1
#     hldid variable paid last wwork2
# 1:     1        1    0    0      0
# 2:     1        2    0    0      0
# 3:     1        3    0    0      0
# 4:     1        4    1    0      0
# 5:     1        5    1    0      0
# 6:     1        6    0    0     -2
# 7:     1        7    1    0     -1
# 8:     1        8    1    1      0
# 9:     1        9    0    0      1
#10:     1       10    0    0      2
#11:     2        1    0    0      0
#12:     2        2    0    0      0
#13:     2        3    1    0      0
#14:     2        4    1    0     -2
#15:     2        5    0    0     -1
#16:     2        6    1    1      0
#17:     2        7    0    0      1
#18:     2        8    0    0      2
#19:     2        9    0    0      0
#20:     2       10    0    0      0
```